# Некорректный рендер JavaFX

Tags: java, gui, javafx, ui, render

Приложение javaFX иногда выводит какие-то белые квадраты(При первом запуске всё нормально, при последующих с каким-то шансом возникают квадраты):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иногда выводит, иногда нет. В чем дело кто-нибуть знает? Ошибок в консоли нет, а белые квадраты есть.
Использую JavaFX-8;
SDK: corretto-1.8 ver. 1.8.0_352

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему. Вызывал функцию, взаимодействующую с элементами Java-FX из потока Java. Решение было простой - Platform.runLater(() -> function)